# Laravel model association advice

Tags: php, laravel, associations, model-associations

2nd association question of the day, sorry.

I have a User model and a Store model.  A Store has many Users, a User belongs to a Store.  That association is easy.

However, there's a second association I'd like to set up between User and Store.  A Store has one manager, and a User can be the manager of many stores.  Store has a field called manager.  So I'd like to be able to be able to do something like this:

```
$store = Store::find($storeId);
echo $store->manager->first_name . " " . $store->manager->last_name;
```

I'm not sure how to set up an association like this.  Store has a field called manager, which matches up with the user_id field in the User model.  Here's what I've tried:

Store model:

```
public function manager() {
    return $this->hasOne('user', 'manager', 'user_id'); //tried belongsTo as well...
}
```

I'm not sure how to specify which fields it should be joining on.  My understanding is that it should match up 'manager' in stores with 'user_id' in users, but my understanding doesn't seem to be correct lol.

...I don't need a manager model do I? I hope not...

EDIT: After Antonio's suggestion:

Store model:

```
public function manager() {
    return $this->hasOne('user', 'user_id', 'manager');
}
```

User model:

```
public function managerOf() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('store', 'stores', 'manager', 'user_id');
}
```

but this still gives me a "Trying to get property of non-object" error...

```
echo $store->manager->user_id;
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `dd($store->manager)`?

Comment: It appears there is some conflicting information here.  Can you explain further `a User belongs to a Store` and `a User can be the manager of many stores`

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro returns this: string 'mrowland' (length=8)

Comment: @user3158900  A user works at a store.  However, a user can have different roles, including manager.  A user can be a manager of many stores.  Store has a field 'manager'.

Comment: Edited to provide more information on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in your store model:

```
public function managerRelation() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('user', 'user_id', 'manager');
}
```

For those columns

```
users->user_id
stores->manager
```

On your User model

```
public function managerOf() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('store', 'stores', 'manager', 'id');
}
```

You should consider adding `_id` to all your id columns, like, manager_id.

EDIT:

Another problem is that `manager` is already a column in your table, so your relation cannot be `manager()`, or you'll have to the column to `manager_id`. I temporarily renamed it to `managerRelation` so you should be able to:

```
echo $store->managerRelation->user_id;
```

Comment: I've updated my question with what you've suggested.  Didn't seem to help though, unfortunately.  Not sure what's wrong now.

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense.  I'm not sure if it worked because now I'm getting another fun error "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!".  Don't understand that at all lol.  I'll have to come back to this later.  Thanks for all your help thus far!

Comment: You now have a recursion, which is exceeding the 100 nesting levels. But I can't really thing where could it be. If you do `dd($store->managerRelation)` you still get this error?

Comment: The database I was working on disappeared over the weekend, so I guess I can't ask for anymore help lol.  Apparently we're using a different database.  Thanks a lot, I'll just mark your answer as the accepted one and move on with my life lol.